# How to iterate over a python dictionary, setting the key of the dictionary as another dictionary's value

Tags: python, list, dictionary, immutability

I come from a C++ background, I am new to Python, and I suspect this problem has something to do with [im]mutability.

I am building a JSON representation in Python that involves several layers of nested lists and dictionaries in one "object". My goal is to call `jsonify` on the end result and have it look like nicely structured data.

I hit a problem while building out an object:

```
approval_groups_list = list()
approval_group_dict = dict()

for groupMemKey, groupvals in groupsAndMembersDict.items():
    approval_group_dict["group_name"] = groupMemKey  
    approval_group_dict["name_dot_numbers"] = groupvals # groupvals is a list of strings
    approval_groups_list.append(approval_group_dict)

entity_approval_unit["approval_groups"] = approval_groups_list
```

The first run does as expected, but after, whatever groupMemkey is touched last, that is what all other objects mirror.

```
groupsAndMembersDict= {
 'Art': ['string.1', 'string.2', 'string.3'],
 'Math': ['string.10', 'string.20', 'string.30']
}
```

**Expected result:**

approval_groups:

```
[
 {
  "group_name": "Art",
  "name_dot_numbers": ['string.1', 'string.2', 'string.3']
 },
 {
  "group_name": "Math",
  "name_dot_numbers": ['string.10', 'string.20', 'string.30']
 }
]
```

**Actual Result**:

approval_groups:

```
[
 {
  "group_name": "Math",
  "name_dot_numbers": ['string.10', 'string.20', 'string.30']
 },
 {
  "group_name": "Math",
  "name_dot_numbers": ['string.10', 'string.20', 'string.30']
 }
]
```

What is happening, and how do I fix it?

Comment: Because you keep assigning *the same list to the same dict* `approval_group_dict["name_dot_numbers"] = groupvals` and subsequently, appending that to `approval_groups_list`. This has nothing to do with mutability/immutability. Simply put, `approval_group_dict["name_dot_numbers"] = groupvals` does not create a copy of `groupvals` and `approval_groups_list.append(approval_group_dict)` does not create a copy of `approval_group_dict`

Answer (score 0):

Through writing this question, it dawned on me to try a few things including this, which fixed my problem - however, I still don't know exactly why this works. Perhaps it is more like a pointer/referencing problem?

```
approval_groups_list = list()
approval_group_dict = dict()

for groupMemKey, groupvals in groupsAndMembersDict.items():
    approval_group_dict["group_name"] = groupMemKey  
    approval_group_dict["name_dot_numbers"] = groupvals 
    approval_groups_list.append(approval_group_dict.copy())  # <== note, here is the difference ".copy()"

entity_approval_unit["approval_groups"] = approval_groups_list
```

---

EDIT: The problem turns out to be that Python is Pass by [object] reference *all the time*. If you are new to Python like me, this means: "pass by reference, except when the thing you are passing is immutable, then its pass by value".  So in a way it **did** have to do with [im]mutability. Mostly it had to do with my lack of understanding how Python passes references.

Comment: Basically, *everything* in Python acts like a reference, nothing is ever implicitly copied.

Comment: yep, that was it.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not the immutability, but the mutability of objects. I'm sure you would have ended up with the same result with the equivalent C++ code.

You construct `approval_group_dict` before the `for` loop and keep reusing it. All you have to do is to move the construction inside `for` so that a new object is created for each loop:

```
approval_groups_list = list()

for groupMemKey, groupvals in groupsAndMembersDict.items():
    approval_group_dict = dict()
    ...
```